# Let $A,B,C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be convex, bounded and closed set, then $A+C=B+C \Rightarrow A=B$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, convex-analysis, subgradient

Here a question and I would like to know if my solution is correct.
I think that it is not needed to use the fact that those sets are convexe, bounded & closed in order to solve the exercice, anyways below is my solution.

**Question:**
Let $A,B,C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ convexe, bounded, not empty & closed set then $A+C=B+C \Rightarrow A=B$
*Reminder:* $A+C=\left \{ a+c : a \in A, c \in C \right \}$

**EDIT: This answer is wrong please see my first post for the answer**

**My solution:**
1-First lets prove that $A\subseteq B$, this is equivalent of proving the following contrapositive statement: $\forall x \notin B \Rightarrow x \notin A$
Now lets suppose by absurd that $x\notin B $ but $x\in A$. In such a case we will have that for any fixed $c' \in C $ that $x+c' \in A+C$. On the other hand by definition $x+c' \notin B+C$ and this is a clearly contradiction to the question because in such a case we get $B+C \subset A+C$.
2-The prove that $B\subseteq A$ is very similar.

Q.E.D.

Is this correct?

Comment: "On the other hand by definition $x+c' \notin B+C$" Why? Certainly we can't write $x + c'$ as $b + c'$ where $b \in B$ (because $x + c' = b + c' \implies x = b$, and $x \notin B$), but why couldn't there be $c'' \in C$ and $b \in B$ such that $x + c' = b + c''$?

Comment: You certainly need *some* hypotheses on $A,B,C$, since $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{2\}$, $C=$ the integers has $A+C=B+C$, $A\ne B$. By the way, "cvexe" in the title?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank for your answer "cvexe=convex"

Comment: I'd recommend using *convex* instead of *cvexe*. It's only one letter longer, and has the advantage that people know what it means.

Comment: I believe the empty set $\varnothing$ is convex, bounded, and closed.  But note $A+\varnothing = \varnothing = B+\varnothing$ even if $A \ne B$.

Comment: @GEdgar The question specifies that the sets are non-empty. This is indeed a true result, even in general normed linear spaces.

Comment: Thank for your help, but does someone has a solution?

Comment: @TheoBendit .. Aha!  The title does not specify non-empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $a \in A$. We wish to show $a \in B$.

Fix $c_0 \in C$. Then $a + c_0 \in A + C \subseteq B + C$. Thus, there exists some $b_1 \in B$ and $c_1 \in C$ such that $a + c_0 = b_1 + c_1$. Further, $a + c_1 \in A + C \subseteq B + C$, so there exist $b_2 \in B$ and $c_2 \in C$ such that $a + c_1 = b_2 + c_2$. Continuing this, we can form a sequence $(c_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and $(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ in $C$ and $B$ respectively, satisfying:
$$a + c_n = b_{n+1} + c_{n+1}.$$
Summing the first $n$ of these equations,
$$na + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} c_i = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i + \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \iff a = \frac{1}{n}\left(c_n - c_0 + \sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right).$$
Since $C$ is bounded, $(c_n - c_0) / n \to 0$. Thus,
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n b_i \to a.$$
As $B$ is convex, this sequence lies in $B$. As $B$ is closed, the limit, $a$, lies in $B$. Thus $a \in B$, as required.

Note: not all premises are necessary here. We actually use no assumptions on $A$; literally any set will work (including the empty set, vacuously). We only require $C$ to be non-empty and bounded (convexity and closedness are optional). We do require $B$ to be convex and closed. It could be unbounded, and it could be empty (though the $B = \emptyset$ case is fairly trivial).

Answer (score 0):

I found a brief answer (not from me) that I develop below with more details. In all the case if someone has an other solution (shorter) I will be happy to read it.

1-
We define the [sub linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublinear_function) function $p_A(x)=Sup \left \{z\cdot x|\forall z\in A  \right \}$ (which is a convex function).
Moreover by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subderivative): $ \partial p_A (x)=\left \{ d \in \mathbb{R}^n|p_A(y)\geq p_A(x)+d\cdot (y-x), \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n \right \}$ and as $p_A(x)$ is a sub linear function we get: $\partial p_A (x)=\left \{ d \in \mathbb{R}^n| p_A(x) \geq d\cdot x, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \right \}$. This means that $\partial p_A (x)$  is the set of all the vectors $d \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that verify $Sup \left \{z\cdot x|\forall z\in A  \right \} \geq d\cdot x$.
It is obvious that $\forall d \in A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ this inequality is verify $\Rightarrow A \subseteq \partial p_A$
On the other hand if $d \notin A \Rightarrow Sup \left \{z\cdot x|\forall z\in A  \right \}$ is not define and hence $d \notin \partial p_A \Rightarrow \partial p_A \subseteq A $
We just proved that $A = \partial p_A, B = \partial p_B, C = \partial p_C$.

2-
By property and what we wrotte above, we know that: $\partial (p_A + p_C)= \partial p_A + \partial p_C= A+C=B+C= \partial p_B + \partial p_C =\partial (p_B + p_C) \Rightarrow \partial (p_A + p_C) = \partial (p_B + p_C) \Rightarrow p_A+p_C=p_B+p_C \Rightarrow p_A=p_B \Rightarrow A=\partial p_A= \partial p_B= B$
Q.E.D.

It is nearly ok but I need help to justify correctly $\partial (p_A + p_C) = \partial (p_B + p_C) \Rightarrow p_A+p_C=p_B+p_C$ is it a property for sub derivative that I don't know?

EDIT: The prove of this step is [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ertr/papers/rtr010-CharSubdiffConvexFn.pdf) and has been given to me by @Theo Bendit

Comment: up can someone help me please?

Comment: Please someone is here O_o ?

Comment: Like with derivatives, if two convex functions have the same subdeifferential, then they differ by a constant. This was proven by [Rockerfellar](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~rtr/papers/rtr010-CharSubdiffConvexFn.pdf) (pdf warning). So, if two sublinear functions, which inevitably pass through $(\vec{0}, 0)$, have the same subdifferential, then they must be the same.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer and time!